# Is it possible to create an SQL query that displays results like this?

Tags: sql-server, excel

### Background

I have a database that hold records of all assets in an office. Each asset have a condition, a category name and an age.

A **ConditionID** can be;

```
In use
Spare
In Circulation
```

**CategoryID** are;

```
Phone 
PC
Laptop
```

and Age is just a field called **AquiredDate** which holds records like;

```
2009-04-24 15:07:51.257
```

### Example

I've created an example of the inputs of the query to explain better what I need if possible.

[image]

NB.

1. Inputs are in Orange in the above example.
2. I've split the example into two separate queries.
3. Count would be the output

### Question

Is this type of query and result set possible using SQL alone? And if so where do I start? Would it be easier to use Ms Excel also?

Comment: your tags include both mysql and mssql: it is a requirement that the query must run on both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, for your orange fields you can just e.g.

```
where CategoryID ='Phone' and ConditionID in ('In use', 'In Circulation')
```

For the yellow one you could do a datediff of days of accuired date to now and divide it by 365 and floor that value, to get the last one (6+ years category) you need to take the minimum of 5 and the calculated value so you get 0 for all between 0-1 year old etc. until 5 which has everything above 6 years.

When you group by that calculated column and select the additional the count you get what you desire.